# A sum regarding prime factorization

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, arithmetic-functions

Prime factorization of $n$ is $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$

Let $f(n) = \left((p_1^{a_1}+1)(p_2^{a_2}+1)(p_3^{a_3}+1)\cdots(p_k^{a_k}+1)\right)$
I want to find the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$$
For example if $N=6$, then the answer is $(1^{1}+1)+(2^{1}+1)+(3^{1}+1)+(2^{2}+1)+(5^{1}+1)+(2^{1}+1)(3^{1}+1) = 32$

Can I find the value without factorizing all the numbers?

$$
1=1 \\
2=2 \\
3=3 \\
4=2^2 \\
5=5 \\
6=2\cdot3 \\
7=7 \\
8=2^3 \\
9=3^2 \\
10=2\cdot5
$$

So for $N=10$ answer is $(1+1)+(2+1)+(3+1)+(2^2+1)+(5+1)+(2+1)(3+1)+(7+1)+(2^3+1)+(3^2+1)+(2+1)(5+1) = 77$

So the sum sums over all $n=1$ to $N$. Same term is not added $n$ times.

Comment: Your question before was strangely written. I edited your sum, do you agree it is correct?

Comment: $(1^1+1)$ should just be $1$, shouldn't it?

Comment: The question edits have lost the original meaning.

Comment: Just two cents: $(p_1^{a_1}+1)\cdots (p_k^{a_k}+1)=\sum_{d\mid n, \gcd(d,n/d)=1}d$.

Comment: @J.J. Judging from the example, I think the edits made the question into what the OP wanted to ask.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to sum up the prime factors of the index. Not of some arbitrary $n$.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: You need to also state that each $p_k$ is distinct because surely $(2+1)(2+1)\neq(2^2+1)$.

Comment: @5xum, the sum extends over all n=1 to N. Each term of the sum is of the form $(p_1^{a_1}+1)(p_2^{a_2}+1)...(p_k^{a_k}+1)$ where $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$

Comment: @Aj Stas, $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ are distinct.

Comment: I actually do not know anymore what the OP wants. What is $N$ supposed to be, how can $n$ run as an index in the sum if it is already defined in the beginning, I have no idea.

Comment: @5xum: He presumably wants $\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{d|n,\gcd(d,n/d)=1} d$.

Comment: @5xum, I have edited the question. I hope there is no doubt now.

Comment: FWIW, the series $2,5,9,14,20,32,40,49,\dots$ is not in OEIS.

Comment: @J.J. thanks for your help. I haven't thought about it.

Comment: @Daniel R: Since the author has the off-by-one to the relevant sequence (because he sets the value for $n=1$ as $2$ instead of $1$), the sequence should be 1,4,8,13,19,31,39,48, which is in OEIS.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A064609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$ where $f(n) = \sum_{d|n, \gcd(d,n/d) = 1} d$ as was noted in the comments by Hagen von Eitzen.

Now changing the order of summation and noting that $n$ is of the form $n = n'd$, we have
$$F(N) = \sum_{d=1}^N \sum_{\gcd(d,n') = 1, 1 \le n' d \le N} d,$$
which we can also write (by replacing $n'$ by $n$) in the form
$$F(N) = \sum_{\gcd(n,d) = 1, 1 \le n d \le N} d$$
where the latter sum now runs over both $n$ and $d$.

Now consider the sum
$$\sum_{1 \le n d \le N} d = \sum_{g=1}^\infty \sum_{\gcd(n,d) = g, 1 \le n d \le N} d.$$
By replacing $n$ by $gn'$ and $d$ by $gd'$, we get that this is equal to
$$\sum_{g=1}^\infty g \sum_{\gcd(n',d') = 1, 1 \le n' d' \le \left\lfloor \frac{N}{g^2} \right\rfloor} d'= \sum_{g=1}^\infty g F\left(\left\lfloor \frac{N}{g^2} \right\rfloor\right).$$
Moving the terms with $g=2,\dots$ to the other side we get the recurrence relation
$$F(N) = \sum_{1 \le nd \le N} d - \sum_{g=2}^{\sqrt{N}} g F\left(\left\lfloor \frac{N}{g^2} \right\rfloor\right).$$

Here the first term is simply $\sum_{d=1}^N d \left\lfloor \frac{N}{d} \right\rfloor$. This can be turned into a pretty fast algorithm by using dynamic programming. See Project Euler for many similar problems utilizing this kind of idea.

Comment: Thank you very much J.J. Nice explanation.